# Unable to change Image Resource in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have the following code and i am unable to change my imageview resource in my program . I have a similar code in another fragment of my program and it works perfectly. I have tried to clean build my project as suggested by other posting.

I tried both

`status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_tick));`
`status.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_cross);`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    status = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.um_namestatus);
    registerButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.um_registerButton);

    name = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.um_name);

    name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_tick)); 
                test();
            }
        }
    });
}

protected void test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_green);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + "//////",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: does the app forceclose? Does the image simply not change? What part of it is not working?

Comment: Hi FoamyGuy , It did not force-close. The app run fine just that the imageview is not changing (in test()) i can see the toast printout on the screen. Thank.

Comment: If your image isn't changing, and your code works perfectly in another fragment, then you probably have misnamed your ImageView and are changing something that isn't visible.

Comment: HI HaIR , You are right i misnamed it . Eclipse have a update reference function in xml layout. I happen to name another imageview same id as this imageview and all references are thus updated. Thanks !